# Issue with Fail2ban and Mikrotik Firewall

Tags: linux, centos, firewall, fail2ban, mikrotik

OS: CentOS 7.1

At my organization we are currently assessing using Fail2ban with the  firewall on our Mikrotik router. I want Fail2ban to communicate any IP flagged as banned to the Mikrotik firewall, creating a new firewall rule. There are three files relevant to this process:

**/usr/bin/mikrotik**

```
-----------------------------------------
#!/bin/bash
ssh -l admin -p22 -i /root/.ssh/id_dsa 192.168.0.1 "$1"
-----------------------------------------
```

**/etc/fail2ban/action.d/mikrotik.conf**

```
-----------------------------------------
# Option:  actionban
# Notes.:  command executed when banning an IP. Take care that the
#          command is executed with Fail2Ban user rights.
# Tags:    <ip>  IP address
#          <failures>  number of failures
#          <time>  unix timestamp of the ban time
# Values:  CMD
#
actionban = mikrotik "/ip firewall filter add action=drop chain=forward dst-address=<ip> comment=AutoFail2ban-<ip>"

# Option:  actionunban
# Notes.:  command executed when unbanning an IP. Take care that the
#          command is executed with Fail2Ban user rights.
# Tags:    <ip>  IP address
#          <failures>  number of failures
#          <time>  unix timestamp of the ban time
# Values:  CMD
#

actionunban =  mikrotik "/ip firewall filter remove [:ip firewall filter find comment=AutoFail2ban-<ip>]"
-----------------------------------------
```

**/etc/fail2ban/jail.local**

```
-----------------------------------------
[sshd]
enabled = true
port    = ssh
filter  = sshd
action  = mikrotik
logpath = /var/log/secure
maxrety = 3
bantime = 120
-----------------------------------------
```

The current issue is that when an IP is flagged to be banned, the entire process of ssh-ing in to the Mikrotik and creating the firewall rule does not occur. Manually running the command `mikrotik` successfully ssh's into the Mikrotik. Manually running the "/ip firewall..." command in the Mikrotik console successfully creates the firewall rule, so I know that the command is correct.

doing a `tail -f` on /var/log/fail2ban.log while causing an ip to be banned gives the error:

```
[10265]: ERROR   /usr/bin/mikrotik -- returned 127 
[10265]: INFO   HINT on 127: "Command not found". Make sure that all commands in '/usr/bin/mikrotik' are in the PATH of fail2ban-server process (grep -a PATH= /proc/`pidof -x fail2ban-server`/environ).
```

However, performing the suggested `grep` command gives:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

Changing the banaction to use ssh will give similar output and state that the command `ssh` is not found.

Any insight in to how we can pass the Mikrotik command via ssh would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried changing `ssh` to `/usr/bin/ssh` (or whatever the full path to the ssh executable is) ?

Comment: Also under what UID is the `/usr/bin/mikrotik` script executed as? If not 0 (=root), then the `ssh` command will not be able to access the private key file under `/root/.ssh/`